# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: el número máximo de expresiones en una lista es 1000

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

estoy tratando de ejecutar una consulta SQL en java, dentro de esta le estoy pasando una cadena String `...colum in ('SOTF','SOTF2','SOTF3','SOTF4','SOTF5'...+1000)` pero me da una excepción:

**java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01795: el número máximo de expresiones en una lista es 1000**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divídelo en mas de una condición:

```sql
...where colum in ('SOTF','SOTF2','SOTF3',...'SOTF999') OR colum in ('SOTF1000',...);
```

O usa TUPLES como lo mencionan en [esta otra respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842453/is-there-a-workaround-for-ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is).

Answer (score 0):

Pues, el error es autoexplicativo. La base de datos (Oracle) te dice que se permiten máximo 1000 elementos en la lista implícita que estás definiendo para la comparación y le estás entregando más que eso. Es un hard limit de la base de datos.

Un camino para poder hacer la comparación que intentas sería crear una tabla temporal en la base de datos y luego hacer el IN comparando con el contenido de la tabla temporal:

```
SELECT ID, NAME, SAL FROM EMP where ID IN (SELECT values from <temporary-table>);
```

Más ideas en [este hilo](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/958612/ora-01795-maximum-number-of-expressions-in-a-list-is-1000-error).